# Cannot get cascading delete to work in EF

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have an entity framework  model on top of a SQL server backend.

I have two tables, Treatment, and Segment.  Treatment has a one-to-many relationship with Segment.  In the DB, I have a cascading delete setup on the foreign key relationship between the tables so that when a Treatment is deleted, all of it's corresponding Segments are also deleted.  This work when I delete a treatment from the DB directly.

In the EF model, I have changed the "End1 OnDelete" property to "Cascade" as well.  However, whenever I try to delete a Treatment, I get the following error:

"The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted."

Here is the code where I delete the Treatment:

```
public bool Delete(Treatment myTreatment)
        {
            bool result = false;

            using (myEntities myObjectContext = new myEntities())
            {
                if (myTreatment.Treatment_ID == 0)
                {
                    result = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (myTreatment.EntityState == System.Data.EntityState.Detached)
                    {
                        myObjectContext.Treatments.Attach(myTreatment);
                    }
                    myObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(myTreatment, System.Data.EntityState.Deleted);
                }
                result = (myObjectContext.SaveChanges() != 0);
            }
            return result;
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

***EDIT***
Here is the CSDL for the Association per @Fauxtrot's request.

```
<Association Name="TreatmentSegment">
          <End Type="tamcModel.Treatment" Role="Treatment" Multiplicity="1" >
            <OnDelete Action="Cascade" />
          </End>
          <End Type="tamcModel.Segment" Role="Segment" Multiplicity="*" >
          </End>
          <ReferentialConstraint>
            <Principal Role="Treatment">
              <PropertyRef Name="Treatment_ID" />
            </Principal>
            <Dependent Role="Segment">
              <PropertyRef Name="Treatment_ID" />
            </Dependent>
          </ReferentialConstraint>
        </Association>
```

Comment: Would it be possible to see your CSDL for this particular Association?

Comment: You should specify cascade delete in database and just update your EF schema. EF will take care of the rest.

Comment: @Hasan can you clarify?  I have the cascade delete specified in the DB.  Shouldn't EF automatically see that and update the relationships itself?  Seems kind of counter-intuitive to have to manually update the EF schema, but if that is the case, how do you suggest I do that?  I've flagged the entity as delete.  Are you saying I should iterate through all the child elements and change their entity state to deleted as well?  What if those child elements also have their own child elements?  Then I have to continue iterating through layers of child elements to properly update the schema?

Comment: You have to right click on EF Designer and click the 'Update model from database' option or something

Comment: @Hasan ya.. I've done that a few times.. lol.  Doesn't seem to make a difference.  In fact, it doesn't even seem to see the cascading delete from the DB.  I have to manually update it and set it to Cascade.  However, once it's manually updated, it does not overwrite it upon subsequent "update from database" attempts.

Comment: @AmandaMyer If you made no other model changes delete your model and import it again

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with it a bit, I stumbled upon the following solution.  I'm posting it here so others in the future who might have this problem can view a solution.

I changed the following line:

```
myObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(myTreatment, System.Data.EntityState.Deleted);
```

To this:

```
myObjectContext.DeleteObject(myTreatment);
```

And now it works....

hmmmm....